# Using ANT to generate a package with a self signed certificate on mac

Tags: macos, ant, nsis, pkgbuild, qz-tray

I am trying build qz.io from source to make it use a self signed certificate.

On this [link](https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/compiling#advanced), they show a way to build from source and sign it with a new certificate:

```
ant nsis -Dauthcert.use=path/to/override.crt
```

However, [here](https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/compiling#steps), they say that `nsis` is used to build on Windows and for Mac, I need to run `ant pkgbuild`:

```
ant nsis       # <-- Windows installer
ant pkgbuild   # <-- Apple installer
ant makeself   # <-- Linux installer
```

So, I tried to run `ant pkgbuild -Dauthcert.use=path/to/override.crt` and it created a new package (.pkg) that can be used on OSX, however, it didn't signed the file with my self signed certificate. But, the `ant nsis` worked fine, creating a `.exe` file signed with my self signed certificate.

I think the `-Dauthcert.use`option is specific for `nsis`.

Do you guys now the proper way to do this on OSX?

Comment: -D is NSIS syntax for a define but this syntax is probably not unique to NSIS, it is inspired by C compilers.

Comment: Anders is right, `-D` isn't platform specific.  In this case, `-Dauthcert.use` is an ant flag that tells the build to copy the file specified into the build directory for packaging.  Assuming it's not a typo, it may be a bug.  https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/2.0/build.xml#L164. You should at least see a message indicating ant picking up this property.  Assuming that works as expected, try to debug the apple script that picks it up.  https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/6762649d4898b64f849d74d5fc29b906812545a1/ant/apple/apple-keygen.sh.in#L81

Answer (score 0):

> it didn't signed the file with my self signed certificate.

For the [build script in question](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/802d1f8f2d47b7c36d9f6c1187a117d0170f6567/build.xml#L110), `authcert.use` is a certificate that the software uses for internal licensing, not for signing the resulting `.pkg` file.  Since multiple certificates are at play, it's important to understand the difference between them.

#### Signing Apple Installer

If you'd like to sign the resulting `.pkg` file, you'll need to obtain an Apple Developer ID, specifically one marked for creating an installer.  To see if one's installed, use `security find-identity -v -p appleID`.

```sh
  security find-identity -v -p appleID

  1) C50DEA4B92E19A5573C48E8CBFCA17A741FF7BC2 "Developer ID Installer:   ABC Incorporated (P4E8D512CX)"
  2) 43A2EF6B7F9EE536B8FA7FB784E5F81D13BDB5D8 "Developer ID Application: ABC Incorporated (P4E8D512CX)"
```

The portion you'll be needing is in parenthesis... You can sign the `.pkg` file by [overriding that value](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/4116e4ec8b9fb9a4d5a2fbcb2c6fe8c5106f64a9/ant/apple/apple.properties#L2).  Note, starting with QZ Tray 2.2.0, both `Application` and `Installer` IDs are required.

e.g.

```sh
ant pkgbuild -Dapple.packager.signid=P4E8D512CX
```

This will pick-up the Apple Signing ID called `P4E8D512CX` from your keyring and use it to sign the `.pkg` file.  This value will change depending on your assigned Apple Developer ID.

Note, for Windows, the procedure is slightly different, you'll need to provide three values: `-Dsigning.alias=...`, `-Dsigning.keystore=...`, `-Dsigning.keypass=...`, `-Dsigning.storepass=...`. Example values are provided [here](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/802d1f8f2d47b7c36d9f6c1187a117d0170f6567/ant/private/private.properties#L1-L4) but generally requires [converting a `.pfx` (PKCS#12) to `.jks`](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/jks-import-export-java.htm).  If you wish to sign the executable after it's created, that will work too, but it won't be applied to any bundled binaries such as the launcher, uninstaller, or DLLs bundled.

#### Overriding Internal Licensing File

The application you're using requires an issued certificate (like a license) to operate.  For users that want to issue their own certificate, the `ant pkgbuild -Dauthcert.use=path/to/override.crt` is valid.  This will create a Desktop installer with the internal license overridden.  For more information about what this license file is for, please see this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X72y6ZZTWzE